# How to add space between 2 buttons in a datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatable-buttons

I have 2 buttons CSV and PDF on my datatable and they seem to be very close to me. I need help on adding some space between them. I tried using 'spacer' button as per https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/spacer.html but nothing works.

[image]

Following is my code:

```
 buttons: [
    {
      extend: 'csv', 
      title: 'Lock Logs for @Model.LockName',
      filename: function () {
        var filename = 'Lock Logs for @Model.LockName ';
        var dt = new Date();
        var currentdatetime = dt.getFullYear() + '-' + (dt.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + dt.getDate() + '_' + dt.getHours() + '-' + dt.getMinutes() + '-' + dt.getSeconds();

        return filename + currentdatetime;
      }
    },
{
   extend: 'spacer'
},
    {
      extend: 'pdf',
      title: 'Lock Logs for @Model.LockName',
      filename: function () {
        var filename = 'Lock Logs for @Model.LockName ';
        var dt = new Date();
        var currentdatetime = dt.getFullYear() + '-' + (dt.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + dt.getDate() + '_' + dt.getHours() + '-' + dt.getMinutes() + '-' + dt.getSeconds();

        return filename + currentdatetime;
      }
    }
  ]
```

Below are my scripts that i am using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Scripts/DataTables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Scripts/DataTables/extensions/Responsive/css/responsive.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/DataTables/extensions/Responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/DataTables/extensions/Buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/DataTables/extensions/Buttons/js/buttons.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/DataTables/extensions/Buttons/js/buttons.html5.js"></script>
```

Comment: "_I tried using 'spacer' button_" - Can you show us your attempt? The spacer works correctly for me when I (a) use BootStrap 5, and (b) the [correct set of official libraries](https://datatables.net/download/index), and (c) the spacer, as shown in the documentation link you have in your question. No custom CSS is needed (in my version).

Comment: Show your attempt as a [mre] - and use CDN links to resources, not local resources where we cannot see exactly what you have downloaded or exactly what libraries and versions you are using. We should be able to copy, paste, and run your MRE without any errors - but with the buttons display issue you are describing.

Comment: @andrewJames Updated my code with adding the extend:spacer but this does not work so wondering if I am missing any library. I am getting error: uncaught cannot extend unknown button type: spacer

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Please re-read the guidance on how to do that. Also, why not download the correct set of library links from the link I provided and try them for yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this css

```
.dataTables_buttons .buttons-csv,
.dataTables_buttons .buttons-pdf {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

This will add 10px of margin to the right of each button. You can adjust the value of the margin-right property to change the amount of space between the buttons.

For example, the following CSS will add 20px of space between the buttons:

```
.dataTables_buttons .buttons-csv,
.dataTables_buttons .buttons-pdf {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

You can also use the spacer button to add space between buttons. The spacer button does not actually display a button, but it does introduce a space between buttons. To use the spacer button, add it to the buttons array after the buttons that you want to separate. For example, the following code will add a space between the CSV and PDF buttons:

```
buttons: [
  {
    extend: 'csv',
    title: 'CSV'
  },
  {
    extend: 'spacer'
  },
  {
    extend: 'pdf',
    title: 'PDF'
  }
]
```

You can also use the spacer button to add space between any two buttons in the buttons array.

Comment: Thanks @dilbert2219, CSS worked but spacer is having issues.